# php curl only works on browser. why?

Tags: php, curl

I have been struggling with this code through out yesterday and today. No suitable answer on this forum that I can apply.I have used the code before and it worked perfectly, I wonder what I am doing wrong. when I enter the url and values on the browser, it works but curl function doesn't. when I checked for error it gave me info:0 but it still doesn't work or post my value.

here is my code

```
    $contact_phone = $_POST['contact_phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    function sendMessage($contact_phone, $message) { 

        $postValue = "sender=$contact_phone&message=$message&pass=***";


        $apiUrl = "http://mydomain.com/components/com_simserver/sim_api.php?";
    //next is to fake a browser form submitted 
    //firefox is our choosing browser
        $browserType = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";

   /initiating the curl library
    $ci = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ci,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
//set the url to be used  for processing the data
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);

//set our browser type that has been initiad before
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $browserType);

//set the maxmium time to execute the script before timing out
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);

//accept the response after the execution 
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// set the post method for passing variables to the server 
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//assigning the values to be posted to the sms gateway
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postValue);

//execute the function and get result from the gateway
    $gatewayResult = curl_exec($ci);

 echo "Info: " . print_r(curl_error($ci)) . "\n";
    curl_close($ci); // close the connection 

    return $gatewayResult; //returning the gateway feedback

    /*   return "Message sent"; */
}


    $smsGateWay = sendMessage($contact_phone, $message);
                     if (isset($smsGateWay))
                {
                    echo "message sent"
                    }

    ?>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="contact_phone" />
    <input type="text" name="message" />
    <input type="submit" value"submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? You're not being clear.

Comment: the "info: 1" is echoing out the return value of the print_r function, right? If you want it to do what I think you expect, you will need
`echo "Info: " . print_r(curl_error($ci),TRUE) . "\n";`
THat might give you an idea of the real error, at least.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
 print_r(curl_errno($ci));
```

you will get the error number,then refer to the link below,this might help.

visit: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. The API/URL doesn't accept posted values so I had to include all the values on the CURLOPT_URL like this
 `$apiUrl = "http://mydomain.com/components/com_simserver/sim_api.php?&sender=$contact_phone&message=$message&pass=***";`